# delete tabs in on all pages except one

Tags: php, wordpress, tabs

I would like to remove an explicit tab in our shop.
Generally no problem either.
But: I would like to keep it in one category (ID = 15)

I found this code to remove the tabs on special pages

what needs to be changed now?

````
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'conditionaly_removing_product_tabs', 99 );
function conditionaly_removing_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
// Get the global product object
global $product;
// Get the current product ID
$product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;
// Define HERE your targeted categories (Ids, slugs or names) <=== <=== <===
$product_cats = array( 'clothing', 'posters' );
// If the current product have the same ID than one of the defined IDs in your array,…
// we remove the tab.
if( has_term( $product_cats, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){
// KEEP BELOW ONLY THE TABS YOU NEED TO REMOVE <=== <=== <=== <===
unset( $tabs['description'] ); // (Description tab)
unset( $tabs['reviews'] ); // (Reviews tab)
unset( $tabs['additional_information'] ); // (Additional information tab)
}
return $tabs;
}```
````

Comment: What is name of category id = 15 ??

Comment: name ="Requests"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I am not a woocommerce expert and neither have worked with it. However, knowing wordpress and how [get terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) work .. you could try some thing as follow.

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'conditionaly_removing_product_tabs', 99 );
 function conditionaly_removing_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    // Get the global product object
    global $product;
    // Get the current product ID
    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;
    // Define HERE your targeted categories (Ids, slugs or names) <=== <=== <===
    // $product_cats = array( 'clothing', 'posters' );

    // lets get all terms and then programatically exclude certain categories
    $terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
                    'orderby' => 'name',
                    'order'   => 'ASC',
                    'exclude' => array( 77, 71 ), // dont forget to include ids for the categories
    ));

    // Loop over the tabs and remove them from the categories
    array_map(function($term) use ($product_id, $tabs){
        if ( has_term($term, 'product_cat', $product_id)){
            unset( $tabs['description'] ); // (Description tab)
            unset( $tabs['reviews'] ); // (Reviews tab)
            unset( $tabs['additional_information'] ); // (Additional information tab)
        }
    }, $terms);

  return $tabs;

}
```